# Ubuntu 16.10 and Adobe AIR installation

Tags: software-installation

Is there already any way to install Adobe AIR in Ubuntu 16.10? I've read many tutorials but it seems that none of them is suitable for Yakkety Yak.
Probably the reason is that 16.10 no longer has `libnss3-1d:i386`. I can't install `libnss3_3.25-1ubuntu1_i386.deb` because of conflict with `libnss3 2:3.26-1ubuntu1`.